# ObjectInputStream corrupted invalid stream header: 79737200 after reloading java program

Tags: java

Program goes like this:
First, I read objects from a file and store them in ArrayList.

```
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("items.dat");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            while(fis.available() > 0) {
                try {
                    Item i = (Item) ois.readObject();
                    items.add(i);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ois.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then I write the objects to the file after editing the objects.

```
try {
            boolean exists = new File("items.dat").exists();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("items.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = exists ? 
                new ObjectOutputStream(fos) {
                    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
                        reset();
                }
            }:new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            for (Item i : items)
                oos.writeObject(i);

            oos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It works completely fine, until I terminate my java program and reload it again.
I am trying to read the objects again (ones I already written in last session) after running my Java program again,  I immediately get this error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 79737200
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:987)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:414)
...
...
...
```

I been trying to fix this for hours now, please help. Thank you!

The program works completely fine in the same session of the running code, the issue is when reloading the java program entirely.

Comment: Do not close ```fos.close();``` directly in second code block.  Use ```oos.close()```.  Better, use Java 7 try-with-resources in both code blocks.
```try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("items.dat")))```.  And just work with `ois`.
and
```try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("items.dat")))```.
Also, why do you need to check if the file already exists in second block? It has to be overwritten always with fresh data, no?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. After doing all what you have suggested, the problem completely solved. And you are right, no need to check if file exists.